# How do I remove a very large folder on Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

My Dropbox folder is duplicated in Dropbox in another folder called dropbox. When I try to delete it from Dropbox online I get a message that it is too large to remove.

How do I remove this folder? It is using up all my space in Dropbox.

Comment: Contact support.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the folder and delete a smaller amount of the data at a time instead of attempting to delete the whole thing at once.  For example, if the second "dropbox" has 20 subfolders within it, try deleting 5 of those at a time.  Once the subfolders are cleaned up, you'll be able to delete the upper-level folder.

If you have Dropbox installed on a computer, you can delete the folder there and wait for it to synchronize.

Alternatively, [contact Dropbox support](https://www.dropbox.com/support) and they can do it for you.

Comment: The problem is that the desktop application takes ages to synchronize…